How can I get the NFT total supply?
I would like to store the total supply of an NFT collection on-chain. However, it seems this value is not in the collection metadata. How can I then obtain this value on-chain?

On a Anchor program, using metadata account the details are stored inside the optional field collection_details
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::metadata::{
    mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata as MplMetadata, MasterEditionAccount, Metadata,
    MetadataAccount,
};

#[program]
pub mod check_metadata {

    use super::*;

    pub fn get_collection_details(ctx: Context<CheckMetadata>) -> Result<()> {
       let size = ctx.accounts.metadata_account.collection_details.unwrap().

    let CollectionDetails::V1 { size } = ctx.accounts.token_metadata_account.collection_details.as_ref().unwrap();
 
       
       Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CheckMetadata<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MplMetadata::find_pda(&mint.key()).0
    )]
    pub metadata_account: Box<Account<'info, MetadataAccount>>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


Before approving this response, is it optional in the sense that a collection nft will necessarily have the collection details or is it up to the dev to set the collection details. i.e could there be a collection with no collection details

not really. It's optional because the metadata program handles single-asset metadata accounts and the collection fields will be None and set when the creator mints a collection. But the authority can manipulate the field.
